# Ruby-on-rails: Get working but Post isn't

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

In very short.
When I have a form set as POST, the controller picks up the request, processes it and even starts to render the correct view. But the browser stays on the form page

When I switch the form to GET, it works
(yes, I remembered to change the route from get to post and back)

Here is the log:

> Started POST "/sooth/search" for 127.0.0.1 at 2022-07-02 13:43:40
> -0700 Processing by SoothController#search as TURBO_STREAM   Parameters: {"authenticity_token"=>"[FILTERED]",
> "search"=>{"name"=>"search keywords"}, "commit"=>"Save Search"}
> Rendering layout layouts/application.html.erb   Rendering
> sooth/search.html.erb within layouts/application
> I am rendering the search html page

The line above is a log message in the `search.html.erb` page

> Rendered sooth/search.html.erb within
> layouts/application (Duration: 1.0ms | Allocations: 148)   Rendered
> layout layouts/application.html.erb (Duration: 6.6ms | Allocations:
> 2710) Completed 200 OK in 15ms (Views: 11.3ms | ActiveRecord: 0.0ms |
> Allocations: 4040)

BUT the search page is not displayed. Browser stays on the search form page.

Any hints deeply appreciated.
(And as you have probably guessed, I am day 1 with rails)

EDIT:

```
class SoothController < ApplicationController
  include SoothHelper

  def index
    puts "sooth index"
    template = get_query_template('sooth_search')
    puts(template)
  end

  def search

    form_params = params[:search]
    puts 'searching' + form_params[:name].to_s
    render "sooth/search"
  end

end
```

ROUTES

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
  Rails.application.routes.draw do
    get "/nlp_data", to: "nlp_data#index"
    get "/sooth", to: "sooth#index"
    post "/sooth/search", to: "sooth#search"

end
```

Comment: can you share the controller file?

Comment: shared. deeply appreciate your attention

Comment: Do you get any error in the browser console ?

Comment: no errors. I shared the entire call with you.
it just doesn't send the oage to the client afaik

Comment: i'm not very familiar with rails 7 but in the request it says Turbo Stream. did you send the request as async if that so perhaps that is the cause of the problem

Comment: not deliberately, but that is a useful clue

Comment: in rails 7 all your redirects need a status to work, like :unproccesable_entity, because turbo_drive usses statuses to know how to handle redirects, but the ok stus is the default status

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is you are trying to render the same page instead of redirecting to to the sooth page ,and secondly you cannot acces params directly in a post request, instead you must acces it from a strong param method

```
class SoothController < ApplicationController
  include SoothHelper

  def index
    puts "sooth index"
    template = get_query_template('sooth_search')
    puts(template)
  end

  def search

    form_params = sooth_params[:search]
    puts 'searching' + form_params[:name].to_s
    redirect_to "/sooth"
  end

  private 
  def sooth_params
   params.require(:sooth).permit(:search)
  end

end
```